# Show that the distance of 2 masses oscillates

Tags: physics, mathematical-modeling

Consider spring-mass system given below
[image: here].

I have calculated that we could model the system by :
    $$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-k(x-l) + k(d-x-y-l)$$
    $$m\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-k(y-l) + k(d-x-y-l)$$
for left mass and right mass where k is the spring constant and $l$ is unstretched length of the spring. Also, all the spring is identical, so they have same spring constant and unstretched length.
The question is, how do I show that distance between left mass and right mass oscillates. The hint is I should define a new variable for this distance.

So, let say $z=d-x-y$. I don't know what to do here. How would I show that $z$ oscillates?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have for each mass

$$
m\ddot x = k(d-x-y)-k x\\
m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(d-y) = -k(d-x-y)+k y
$$

if $z = d - x - y$ then subtracting the first from the second

$$
m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(d-x-y) = -2k(d-x-y)-k(d-x-y)+ kd
$$

or

$$
m\ddot z +3kz = kd
$$

or

$$
z = C_1 \sin \left(\sqrt{\frac{3k}{m} t}\right)+C_2 \cos \left(\sqrt{\frac{3k}{m} t}\right)+\frac{d}{3}
$$

Comment: Nice, your answer is the same with the book. One question, I guess the \textcolor{red}{red} part of $m \ddot {\textcolor{red}{z}} = k\textcolor{red}{(d -3z)}$ need not to be equal for us to conclude that $z$ oscillates? sorry, I just start this topic. Also, is yours any different than the other answer or it is just another way so express it? Thanks in advance

Comment: Oscillates because the dynamic described by the resulting differential equation corresponds to an oscillator.

Comment: A one dimensional harmonic oscillator is described by $\ddot z + \omega^2 z = c$

Comment: Where you get $m\ddot x = k(d-x-y)-k x$ and $m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(d-y) = -k(d-x-y)+k y$ from?

Comment: I followed the figure indications and ordered the mass center' s with origin at the left corner. The dynamical equation is typical for a mass-spring setup.

Comment: I understand the first equation, but the second one is a bit trickier. Why would we have spring force $-k(d-x-y)$ be negative, unlike the same part in first equation. What direction is this spring force? We also has positive spring force $ky$, unlike the same in first equation.

Comment: This is a theme of action - reaction and Newton laws. Here is not the place to extend basic mechanical concepts such as those. I suggest you to revise the basic mass-spring dynamics.

Comment: Any way, the forces $m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}(d-y)$ and $-k(d-x-y)$ are of opposite sign as due.